# Weird issue facing with spark-sql

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below 3 sqls.

```
select count(distinct visitor_id)
from df_and_lkp_join_cache
--178996 

select count(distinct trim(visitor_id))
from df_and_lkp_join_cache
--178996

select count(distinct visitor_id)
from (select a.visitor_id, a.ip, b.visitor_id as visitor_id_b
      from df_and_lkp_join_cache a inner join
           df_not_matching_lkp b
           on a.ip = b.ip
      )
--628259
```

As my joins is not on the columns visitor_id i expect to receive output count for 3rd sql to be less or equal to 178996. But the count is increasing.

I am unable to understand this behavior of spark-sql. Please help me if i my expectation is wrong. What going wrong here.

Comment: Your expectation seems correct.  I cannot readily think of an explanation, assuming that the data does not change between the queries.